# Is ancestry.com DNA test accurate with respect to native american descent?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, native-american

Both myself and my wife believe we are descendants (each on the order of 1/16) of native americans, yet for the Ancestry.com autosomal DNA test, the ethnicity estimate shows nothing for native american, and everything from Europe.

How accurate are these estimates?  We were both pretty sure we were descendants of Cherokees.  Family photos, appear to look native american.

Comment: Your question is partially addressed in the answers to this question on [generational loss in DNA data](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6668/generational-loss-of-data-with-dna-testing).  My answer has a list of DNA experts who blog, who may have already talked about this problem.  If you find an answer in their blogs, it is okay (in fact, it's encouraged) to write up the summary of what you found in an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me as well at Ancestry. I did 2 things. I took another DNA test thru another company and found out that I have 2 markers for Native Americans; they also have an extensive database!! I also downloaded my Ancestry.com results and uploaded to Gedmatch.com. I then saw my Native American results and could even see how much on each chromosome.

Note: Some Cherokees are very mixed. Some have quite a bit of European - also remember that not a lot of Native Americans have tested with Ancestry, so maybe you don't match with what they currently have in their database.

I encourage you to download your results and go to Gedmatch.com.

Let me know if you want anymore info.

Comment: I have my results uploaded to gedmatch as well as familytreedna.  How do I see the native american results on gedmatch?  Does that require tier1 tools?

Comment: @WilliamKF I saw a posting on a blog that recommended using Dodecad World9, Eurogenes K13 for Native American traits. I don't have any though to test it out to prove that though.