# Autosomal DNA Chromsome Browser - Is there such a thing as a 'family trait' of shared segments?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna

I realize the passing of genes is approximately 50/50 ([reference Generational Loss of Data with DNA testing](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6668/generational-loss-of-data-with-dna-testing)) with each generation and which genes are passed are commonly referred to as 'random' based on existing science.

I [read the tutorial](https://www.familytreedna.com/learn/user-guide/family-finder-myftdna/chromosome-browser/) and then watched the FamilyTreeDNA hour plus long tutorial video on using the Chromosome Browser as well as some videos on their [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGXMVPJ5TBwcIvvRt3XWpDw).

Like pointed out in one of the videos.. the 50/50 does not always apply and certain chromosomes can be preserved across generations.

Looking at my known relatives to a common shared ancestor I noticed this in Chromosome 1.

The main display person (dark blue background) and GREEN are half-siblings and share a common ancestor pair who is there great-grandX.

- Purple is the grand son of dark blue.
- Blue is GGGG-granddaughter of the common pair from a completely different
  child of the common pair.
- Orange is a GGG-granddaughter of another child of a common ancestor pair.
- Yellow is one of about 4 others of 350 matches who have a small sliver in the that same segment of that area.

[image]

This segment starts at 202478548 and in the matches so far go for at least 19.29 cMs to 217120123 (the orange).

Is there such a thing as a common family pair segment region (i.e. the 202.. to 217..) that could be considered something like a "trait" (terminology may not be correct) that can be used to hone in on a specific set of relatives (or one of their ancestors) and should it be specifically looked for or utilized as a tool even at smaller segment sizes?

In other words, I realize I should look for other alignments / strong matches / longer segments as well but is it a proven and reasonable technique to hone in on a specific segment range of a single Chromosome to identify a particular relative?

[image: Partial Chromosome browser screenshot]
Note: I am only showing part of the overall chromosome browser as I found the part of Chromosome one unique for such distance matches.

Comment: I've read through this several times but I'm not really clear what you're asking. Your terminology is slightly confusing - you don't find 'traits' in DNA (you find genes that encode for traits). Is your question basically whether the fact that all 5 people share the same small segment in chromosome 1 suggests they all share a common ancestor?

Comment: @vervet Kind of, I KNOW they share a common ancestor set (Father/Mother) which were born 200 years ago but descend from different children of that set. I am asking is it reasonable to try to use that common shared segment to locate other matches of that pair of common ancestors or possibly even further back?